# No local administrator passwords found - Intune LAPS

Tags: intune

So I have been scratching my head over this from last 3 days. I think I have gone through almost all the articles.

I have enabled LAP from Azure AD:

[image]

THen below is my powershell script to create the local admin account:

```
# Define the username for the new admin account
$username = "Company-admin"

# Generate a random password with specified complexity: large letters, small letters, numbers, special characters
function Generate-Password {
    $PasswordLength = 14
    $PasswordChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*"
    $SecurePassword = -join ($PasswordChars | Get-Random -Count $PasswordLength)
    return $SecurePassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
}

$SecurePassword = Generate-Password

# Create the new local user and set it as an administrator
$user = New-LocalUser -Name $username -Password $SecurePassword -FullName "Company Admin" -Description "Local Administrator Account Managed by LAPS"
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $user.Name
```

Now I have checked and this script gets successfully executed by intune and admin account is created.

Now below is my LAPS profile of intune:

[image]

Now the settings are showing successfully applied:

[image]

But when I go to device and Local admin password, it shows below:

[image]

I even tried rotating the local admin password still no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I decided to use the default admin and have GP rename it.  LAPS picks it up without having to configure the user name since it defaults to the default admin account.  Key thing is to make sure the account is enabled.  I have it working for all new machines but one that was added a while back is the only one that refuses to work same as you show.  I may need to re-enroll that machine :(